# Need only sign transaction feature (not send transaction)

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

I am developing an online store BNB as a payment. Customers will sign transactions using Metamask and then frontend code(js) need to post call to our backend server with the txHash, and then we will broadcast the transaction to the network using our backend service.

But I am not able to find it using `web3.js( web.eth.account.signTransaction()` will not work in my case as we don't customer private keys).

I Need to know how to with web3 or with Metamask js library, any example of code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to sign a transaction without broadcasting it with Metamask. The reason behind this is that such an approach would break the current account nonce management system of Metamask. There is a Github thread about this : https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475.

I see two ways to overcome this limitation :

- Use the deprecated Metamask `eth_sign` method which enables to sign an arbitrary hash and therefore a transaction hash (this would not be possible with `personal_sign` which adds a specific prefix to the message before hashing it, making the signature of transactions impossible). Note that this way of doing is not very clean and could be hard to implement. Furthermore, it is very unsafe for the user who doesn't know what he is actually signing. In fact, trying to get the user to sign a transaction with `eth_sign` could be considered an attack.
- Implement a meta-transaction system : A much cleaner way of doing. Ask the user to sign a message and from this message sign a transaction in your backend. I wrote a simple exemple in an answer to this post : [ETH - Pre-Paid smart contract so users don't pay transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88268/eth-pre-paid-smart-contract-so-users-dont-pay-transactions/88276#88276).

Comment: [web3]https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#signtransaction and [wiki]https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#json-rpc-methods shows the method but when I used them it shows **'eth_signTransaction' does not exist**.

Comment: Metamask does not support this method. So if you try to call it with Metamask in your frontend it will fail. As I said in my answer, there is currently no way to properly sign a transaction without broadcasting it with Metamask.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert
can we `eth_sign` for payment as well? It does not support the same params as other methods for payment.
The second way looks more complex to implement so are there any other browser-wallets available that support the `signTransaction` feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "can we eth_sign for payment as well? It does not support the same params as other methods for payment." ?

Comment: For the other browser wallets I don't know.

Comment: What you can do with `eth_sign` is sign a transaction hash. So you first build your transaction in your frontend, then ask the user to sign the hash. After that you send the hash to the backend and finally you send the signed transaction to the network.

Comment: Can we use `eth_sign` for the same purpose as `eth_signTransaction` it?
Input params for `eth_sign` are not the same as from, to, value gas, gasPrice.
So If I want to sign a transaction for 0.1 ETH, can we do with using the method `eth_sign`?

Comment: Yes but it will be hard as you will need to build yourself the transaction in your frontend (rewrite `eth_signTransaction`), doing very low-level operations such as the RLP-encoding of the transaction, get the account nonce, extract the ECDSA r,s,v parameters of the signature, etc.

Comment: From my point of view the meta-transaction system is by far the better approach.

Comment: Also trying to make the user sign a transaction with `eth_sign` can be seen as malicious because the user doesn't know what he is actually signing.

Comment: Yes it is a problem with `eth_sign` and for the second way actually, I don't have a smart contract, the user just will buy a product from the application and he just needs to send the money to my address that will be inside the javascript(to params).

Comment: Ok, then maybe you should rethink your system. Why do you need a backend ? Why simply don't let the user directly send the transaction ?

Comment: Flow for my use-case
1.UI will call my products API
2.User will click on buy and popup should come to sign the tx(not send) using Metamask/wallet
3.UI will get back the signed tx hash.
4.UI will do the POST call to my buy API
5.Now backend will broadcast the tx to blockchain and after successful tx will give the product to the user

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do this than the previous 2 or let the user broadcast the transaction himself.

Comment: have you implemented the second solution already?

Comment: Yes, works fine. You should definitely make some researches on meta-transactions to see if it suits your use case . Good luck.