# Should all state-changing functions to a smart contract go through MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, dapps, infura, web3-providers, alchemy

For a Dapp that is using its own node provider such as Infura or Alchemy, all read operations can go through this node, but any state-changing operations will require a signer. These node providers do not have a signer because they don't store private keys.

Is it better to use MetaMask for all write operations, or should that still go to your Infura/Alchemy node?

If the latter, would the user have to sign a transaction using MetaMask, and that gets sent to your node provider? Will MetaMask pick up those transactions and display it under activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it better to use MetaMask for all write operations, or should that
> still go to your Infura/Alchemy node?

You can use any wallet you want, but in the end the transaction must be forwarded to a node (*e.g.,* Infura, Alchemy, local node) so that it can broadcast it to the blockchain.

It's just about signing the tx locally to then forward it to a node, which in the case of Metamask is Infura by default anyway.

> If the latter, would the user have to sign a transaction using
> MetaMask, and that gets sent to your node provider? Will MetaMask pick
> up those transactions and display it under activity?

Yes and yes. Metamask will watch for your transactions and give you status update on your tx as well as provide you with a history of past transactions involving your account, both sent and received.

Comment: Thanks @hroussille.Is the latter actually possible? I read https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90011/99637 and it seems it's not possible or good practice to get metamask to sign a transaction, and send that to your own node. It's slightly different, but same concept that I am trying to use metamask to sign a transaction for me, that I can use to broadcast to my infura node (not metamask's default node).

Comment: No what they are saying is that Metamask will not hold a signed transaction, it will be forwarded to the node immediately. You are free to configure a network in Metamask using your own provider node. Your tx will be signed with Metamask and instantly sent to your node for broadcasting.

Comment: I see, but that would only apply to my browser, but other users on my Dapp would have to use what node they have configured or the MetaMask's default provider.

Comment: yes, and chances are they won't change it for just one app :/